# I delete the script but when put back it says it already exists

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm doing a "one page" site, where the main script removes and adds the script to each page.

But ... when you reload the previous page it duplicates the script, so duplicating the existing functions.

**This is the changing page script:**

```
let scriptBody = null;
function GetPageOnBody(page) {
    $.get("pages/"+page+".html", function(site){
        if(scriptBody != null) removejsfile(scriptBody);
        $('#pageBody').html(site);

        scriptBody = document.createElement('script');    
        switch(page){
            case "login":
                window.document.title = "LOGIN - DASHBOARD";
                scriptBody.setAttribute('src', "assets/js/page-login.js");
                break;
            case "home":
                window.document.title = "HOME - DASHBOARD";
                scriptBody.setAttribute('src', "assets/js/page-home.js");
                break;
            case "artigos":
                window.document.title = "ARTIGOS - DASHBOARD";
                scriptBody.setAttribute('src', "assets/js/page-artigos.js");
                break;
         }   
         document.body.appendChild(scriptBody);
    }).fail(function(){
        // error 404 page
    }).done(function(){
        // show page
    });
}
```

**This is the code to remove script:**

```
function removejsfile(script){
    let filename = script.getAttribute("src").split("/").slice(-1);
    let allscripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (let i = allscripts.length; i >= 0; i--){
        if (allscripts[i] && allscripts[i].getAttribute("src") != null && allscripts[i].getAttribute("src").indexOf(filename) != -1)
            allscripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(allscripts[i]);
    }
    delete script;
}
```

I already tried several ways, but none succeeded.

Thank you

Comment: When a js file is loaded, the functions in it are added to window. To take an example, in your page, you should be able to call window.GetPageOnBody() in console. So you can't just remove the script tags, you must also remove the things which were added elsewhere

Comment: This looks like you're trying to implement security aspects (login?) in JS. This is a bad idea, because JS is client-side only and can be read and modified by the client without any chance to prevent this by the server. For any help here, you should [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Then how do i remove the functions(script) that already were added to the window? That aspects of security are not relevent cause this works with socket.io